# Compiling error with boost::equality_comparable in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have minimised the example code to reproduce this error:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

// Evil
namespace Evil
{
    using BadGirl = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
    class BadBoy
        : public boost::totally_ordered2<BadBoy, BadGirl>
    {
    public:
        BadBoy() {}
    };
}

// Civilians
class Base // Abstract class inherited from boost::equality_comparable to get != operator for free
    : public boost::equality_comparable<Base>
{
    friend bool operator == ( Base const & lhs, Base const & rhs );    

public:
    Base() {}

    virtual void Whatever() const = 0;
};
// Implementation of equality operator
bool operator == ( Base const & /*lhs*/, Base const & /*rhs*/ )
{
    return true;
}

class Derived
    : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    void Whatever() const override {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived * derived1 = new Derived();
    Derived * derived2 = new Derived();
    Base * base1 = derived1;
    Base * base2 = derived2;

    // Calling the operator from the base class
    bool result = *base1 != *base2; // != operator is got for free from boost::equality_comparable.
    return 0;
}
```

The `Evil` part of the code would cause a failure during compiling, complaining that `cannot instantialize abstract class (base)`. But it is only reproducible with `cl`. G++ has no issues of building and running it.

Any idea why the absolutely independent class inside namespace `Evil` could cause an error in class `Base` and `Derived`? So far I only found `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` could trigger this, but there might be other cases that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I suggest you test it with clang too and report to MS devs if it is successful there.

Comment: With clang it could be compiled successfully.